# rich:autocomplete not showing in the browser

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm doing a Rich Faces tutorial, I'm done with code but when I deployed the project the rich:autocomplete box did not appear in the browser, I have tried different browsers and still the same

here is  my code 
`test.xhtml`

```
 <body>
    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">
        Richfaces sample validation and auto-completion Updated
        </f:facet>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="Enter your name" />
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{UserBean.name}">
                <rich:validator />
            </h:inputText>

            <rich:message for="name" />
            <br />

            <h:outputText value="Enter your state" />
            <rich:autocomplete mode="ajax" showButton="true" value="#{UserBean.state}" minChars="1"
                autocompleteMethod="#{UserBean.autocomplete}" />
        </h:form>
    </rich:panel>
</body>
```

the `UserBean.java` code is

```
    @ManagedBean
public class UserBean {

    public List<String> autocomplete(String prefix) {

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        result.add("England");
        result.add("France");
        result.add("Germany");
        result.add("Italy");
        result.add("Spain");

        return result;
    }

    @Size(min=3, max=12,message="Must be between 3 and 12 chars")
    private String name;

    private String state;

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

this is 'web.xml'

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
version="3.0">
  <display-name>rich</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

when I run the war file in the browser it shows like this:

[image: Running Project in the browser]

while the actual preview in the Eclipse showing like this:

[image: The Eclipse Preview]

Comment: What does the HTML look like? (in your browser)

Comment: Solved by replacing the old jars with a new one. :)